# 「期間」と「時期」の違いは何ですか

Tags: word-choice

「期間」と「時期」という言葉の違いは何ですか。いつ、どのように使えますか。

Comment: あーた、また丸投げ？　辞書を調べてみて、今のところどういう相違点や類似点が（（以下同文

Comment: 投稿する前に、辞書を調べてみたけど、同じ言葉あったから、ちゃんと分からなかったよ！だから、投稿しました！私は日本人ではないし、ペラペラもないです。

Comment: 国語辞書に期間と時期を探して、同じ言葉あるわけはありません。言い換えると、何が何と同じ言葉は不明です。

Answer (score 3):

期間 tends to refer to a time period that has a well-defined start and end. A 期間 can be very long. 時期 usually refers to a vague time period and it can be better translated as "time (suitable) for ～", "time around ～" or "～ season". Examples:

> - 試験の申し込み**期間**は9月1日から9月30日です。
> - オリンピックの**期間**も休まず営業します。
> - 産まれてから成人するまでの**期間**
> - クリスマスの**時期**が近づいています。
> - この**時期**はほとんど毎日雨が降ります。
> - 田植えをするにはまだ**時期**が早いです。

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary:
期間: a period of time.
時期: a crucial or appropriate time

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/期間/#je-15552](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%9C%9F%E9%96%93/#je-15552)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/時期/#je-30696](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%99%82%E6%9C%9F/#je-30696)